# Calling a different class every time using onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a system where there exist `ImageView`s, which are under `LinearLayout`s. I wish to set an onClickListener to every `ImageView` that calls the same method (programmatically, obviously, not through XML), but passing a different variable, let's call it `action(int i)`, where `i` is the "global index" of the `ImageView`s. Since `i` is a variable used throughout my MainActivity, simply putting `action(i);` in the method won't work, because I need to pass the specific object's global index. Is there any way I can do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to display your images?

Comment: @PPartisan : how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: I'm using a `ScrollView`, under which there is a vertical `LinearLayout`. Then, from `MainActivity` I add horizontal `LinearLayout`s, under the vertical one, that each contain `ImageView`s.

Comment: @ParagKadam Because if he is, you can supply an `int[]` of image resource ids to the adapter, and access the correct index from the row position. The fact the OP mentions several image views in a linear layout suggests he could be using a list of some sort.

Comment: @PPartisan : Good assumption...Point taken :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to a call method like `action(index_of_the_imageView_that_is_clicked)`? That is a lot of imageViews, but at any event if that is what you are trying to do, would it be possible to set up a hashmap that maps the ImageViews to their global index and then when an ImageView is clicked, use the `get(imageView)` method of the hashmap to get the global index.

Comment: I did a bit of research on it, but how will the OnClick class look for the pair of values it needs?

Comment: I think the onClick(view) gives you the view that was clicked which should be the imageView if the  listener is attached to it. You might need to cast it to ImageView if the hashmap is mapping ImageViews or you can map Views instead. So you would do hashmap.put(imageView, global_index) to put them in the hashmap and hashmap.get(view) in the onClick(view) { ...} to get the global index_back.

Comment: Or I could just put the global index in each imageview's contentDescription and fetch it later by using the view. Thank you very much, I will try both.

Comment: I like the concept and think it is a step in the right direction. I would suggest considering setTag() and getTag() instead since contentDescription is meant to be used for accessibility.

Comment: I know it's used for accessibility and such, but the app I am creating is very visual, so I doubt accessibility is something I can really implement. Also, the Tag system was definitely not working the way I wanted it to. It now works with the content description system. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        imageClicked(1);
        }
}
.
.   //More imageViews here
.
imageView10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        imageClicked(10);
        }
}

public void imageClicked(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:   //Code for when imageView1 is clicked
        break;
        .
        .
        .
        case 10:  //Code for when imageView10 is clicked
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this definitely does not help. I mentioned that I add the `ImageView`s programmatically. That is because these images should be allowed to be very many. If the thing I mentioned on the question does not work, I will try to rework the whole concept or ditch the feature altogether.

Comment: You have no where in you question mentioned that you are trying to add the image views dynamically. You should probably re-structure your question properly so that other users can easily understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
class yourSpecialListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
   private int globalInd;
   public yourSpecialListener(int par_globalInd)
   {
     globalInd=par_globalInd;
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
    action(globalInd);
    }
}
```

Make this as inner class to your class.
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new yourSpecialListener(getyourimageviewid));
imageView2.setOnClickListener(new yourSpecialListener(getyourimageviewid));
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
View.OnClickListener customOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            action(view.getId()));
        }
    };

yourImageView1.setOnClickListener(customOnClickListener);
yourImageView2.setOnClickListener(customOnClickListener);
....

public void action(int imageId) {
    // Do your job in terms of the imageId
}
```